# Will connecting points on a convex function in increasing order always produce a convex piecewise linear function?

Tags: convex-analysis

Let us have an one-variable **convex** function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Given a strictly monotone sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Form the piecewise linear function from the corresponding points on the graph by connecting them in the  correct order (we connect $(a_i,f(a_i))$ and $(a_{i+1},f(a_{i+1}))$ for all $i$ from $1$.

Is it necessary that the newly-formed piecewise linear function must be a convex function? This question has been bugging me a lot.

I can tell that the answer is highly to be positive, from some sketches I draw. But somehow the proof is not obvious to me.

Did I make a mistake, or I overlooked something? Please give me a hint.

Thank you for reading.

EDIT: I forgot to put $f$ as a convex function. The answer would be obvious otherwise.

Comment: Yes. You can prove the slopes are nondecreasing. Then, you can prove that any continuous piecewise linear function with nondecreasing slopes is convex (just integrate the slope as a function of $x$).